# Electrical Engineering

Tags: power-electronics

I used a 2N3055 powerTrans with a collector transformer (6-220v)load with an audio input base bias from a  audio source , I am getting 160vAC from 6v DC , i want 220 v AC out , Can anyone suggest a solution

Comment: What is the semi-conductors to do with it

Answer (score -1):

Respected sir/madam,
    we can get the desired 220V Ac Output by giving the arrived 160V AC output as input to the step up transformer.
                                        Thank you.